# ¿Método en Javascript para editar el estado en React de manera inmutable, usando una referencia de comparación?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Mi objetivo es intentar cambiar (añadir, porque está vacio) un valor en el state, concretamente el valor `idApi: ""`

```
state = {
      items_local: [{ "name": nombreTask, "id": itemsCounter, idApi: "" }
}
```

Esto lo quiero hacer así porque cuando el usuario quiere eliminar un objeto en `items_local`, necesito que también se borre en la API REST. Pero no tengo el id de este elemento porque se ha generado automáticamente con POST:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/task', {
      name: nombreTask,
      list: this.state.id_lista
    }).then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }
```

Entonces mi intención es la siguiente. Inmediatamente después de que se haga la peticion POST creando la task, (y además ya exista en su correspondiente `items_local` ) pues se lo quiero añadir de esta manera:

```js
createTask = (event) => {
// AÑADIR LA TASK DE MANERA LOCAL:
event.preventDefault()
const nombreTask = event.target.elements.nombretask.value;

let itemsCounter = this.state.items_local.length;
this.setState(prevState => ({
  items_local: [{ "name": nombreTask, "id": itemsCounter, idApi: "" }, ...prevState.items_local]
}))
// AÑADIR LA TASK EN LA API 
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/task', {
  name: nombreTask,
  list: this.state.id_lista
}).then((res) => {
    // --pseudocodigo:
    // METER EL _id del backend en el valor idApi del state :
    this.state.items_local.map((item) => {
      if(item.name === res.data.name){
          item.idApi = res.data._id
      }
  })
}).catch(error => console.error(error))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo así

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  items_local: [ ...prevState.items_local.map(item => {
    if(item.name === res.data.name){
      item.idApi = res.data._id
    }
    return {...item};
  }) ]
}))
```

como referencia podrías leer el siguiente link donde explican el operador de propagación, que su uso devuelve objetos inmutables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], considera editar y agregar una explicación